# How to add objects of a generic interface to a dictionary, when the generic type definition could both be value and reference types?

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic interface:

```
interface ITask<T>
{
    T exec(T input);
}
```

This generic interface is implemented with type definitions of both value types and reference types:

```
// interface implemented with value type `int`
class IntTask: ITask<int>
{
    public int exec(int input)
    {
        // some code
        return input;
    }
}

//interface implemented with reference type `object`
class ObjectTask: ITask<object>
{
    public object exec(object input)
    {
        // some code
        return input;
    }
}
```

I have various objects of these two classes:

```
var intTask = new IntTask();
var objTask = new ObjectTask();
```

I want to collect these objects to an instance if `IDictionary<string, X>`. And I am not sure what to use for `X`.

What I have tried so far:

#### `Dictionary<string, ITask<object>>`

```
var taskList = new Dictionary<string, ITask<object>>();
taskList.Add("object", objTask);
taskList.Add("int", intTask);
```

This produces following errror:

> The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary>.Add(string, IntObjectTest.ITask)' has some invalid arguments.

#### `Dictionary<string, ITask<object>>`, but value of the key-value-pair casted to `ITask<object>`

```
taskList.Add("int", (ITask<object>)intTask);
```

This compiles fine, but produces runtime error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'IntObjectTest.IntTask' to type 'IntObjectTest.ITask`1[System.Object]'.

#### `Dictionary<string, ITask<dynamic>>`

This is pretty much same as `Dictionary<string, ITask<object>>` because dynamic is a *reference* type that is resolved in runtime and cannot be used for value types.

---

So my question boils down to **what generic type `X` can I use such that a generic method/interface can be implemented with both reference and value types?** Can I do this at all?

Comment: There is no type X that can do this aside from object (that is have `IDictionary<string, object>`). The interface is invariant with respect to T (it appears in both input and output positions). Also variance is only supported for reference types, never value types.

Comment: Thanks @mikez. I will probably have to resort to some sort of boxing to pull this off, then.

Comment: Have you considered adding non generic ITask interface? It would solve the problem with storing. You can inherit all your generic interfaces from the one non generic.

Comment: Thanks, @cassandrad. Yes, that would work. But that means I have to use reflection to check types every time I call `exec`. Maybe there is no alternative other than that.